# Browsable(false) and svcutil

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm using svcutil to generate service reference code for a client and want to replicate the "add service reference" option in Visual Studio 2010. I've followed advice found [enter link description here](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2008/06/30/equivalent-svcutil.exe-command-for-vs2008-add-service-reference.aspx). The only issue I face is that it's not marking the ExtensionDataObjects with the Browsable(false) attribute - as is the case when you generate the reference files from Visual Studio.

I'm hoping it's just a switch I'm missing as I don't want to go down the route of writing something custom to apply the attribute after svcutil does it's magic.

Here's the generated code for reference:

```
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
```

This is what VS generates via *"Add Service Reference"*

```
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
```

**Follow up:**

So I haven't found a solution for this and it's not bothering me too much. Some day I might try to properly replicate Visual Studio's method for generating these classes.

I should explain why I asked this question though - I switched from the VS method to the svcutil method. An "Update Service Reference" is now part of my build process. The problem is that I have a few grids / binding sources that now have this visible ExtensionData column. Not ideal.

Comment: I cannot read your question .. what's the issue?

Comment: It's not that surprising, since `Browsable` is all about the design-time experience and the properties window - `svcutil` has neither of these concepts, and it would be somewhat odd if it cared about such. Whereas VS has both design-time experiences and a properties window ...

Comment: So, would you think it's impossible to replicate the way Visual Studio creates the reference code exactly?